# Crystal report showing records in one line

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, report, records

I have three records in my table and I want to display those records in one line and on one page.

I will only ever have three records as my SQL command restricts the dataset to three records.

How can I fit these three records on one page on a single line using Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Section Expert` go to the `Details` section, `Common` and tick `Format with multiple columns`.

[image: Details Section - Common]

A new tab appears- `Layout`. From this tab you need to define the size and behaviour (across then down or down then across).

[image: Details Section - Layout]

Save your changes and you should then see something along the lines of this in the Designer.

[image: Designer View - Multiple Column Layout]

Comment: That dont works for me :( CR steel shows me the records verticaly, i want to show them horizontaly

Comment: can you show screenshots of the design view, preview and section expert configuration?

Comment: sorry dude im at work and i dont have acces to snapshot button, all that iv done is choosing cross then down, it dont works, and after i choose down then cross, and its the same think

Comment: I have edited this answer and added some screenshots to this answer to make it a bit clearer. Remember that you **have** to specify the width property in the `Layout` tab or it won't work properly.

Comment: Okey it works for me! the probleme was the width property! thanks guys! Peace :)